# jQuery append or appendTo after an img

Tags: jquery, append, image, appendto

I cannot get this simple append working.  I'm trying to add two break tags AFTER the first Image.
    
      
        
        
          
          
          This is a link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.photosize').find('img:first').append('<br/><br/>');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`append()` inserts the elements as a **child** of the element it applies to.  Use [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead:

```
$('.photosize').find('img:first').after('<br/><br/>');
```

Comment: That's what I suspected but it doesn't seem to do anything unfortunately.

Comment: @ToddN: it works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/Ns7AP/.  Which browsers have you tested it in?

Answer (score 0):

This already works, with caveats:

1) When you call `$.append()` it appends the string to the innerHTML of the element you are appending to. So for this instance it will add two line breaks to the innerHTML of the image element. Try using `$.after()` instead:

`$('.photosize').find('img:first').after('<br/><br/>');`

2) The `:first` selector doesn't work in many (if not all) versions of IE. You can fix this by selecting it using an ID or class instead of the pseudo class `:first`

Answer (score 0):

Do this (**it's tested and works**):

```
$('.photosize img').first().after('<br/><br/>');
```

Hope this helps. Cheers